# How to merge two large POJO's in java?

Tags: java

How do I merge 2 large identical POJO's(~40 fields) in Java?

Example

```
Satellite A: [name = ISS, period = 0.9, inclination = 0.8, launch_date=2016-01-04, launch_vehicle=null, has_propulsion=null]

Satellite B: [name = International Space station, period= 0.91, inclination =0.802, launch_vehicle=BOAT, has_propulsion=false]
```

Into

```
Satellite C: [name = ISS, period = 0.9, inclination = 0.8, launch_date=2016-01-04, launch_vehicle=BOAT, has_propulsion=false]
```

Comment: Why not a constructor with all fields and set whichever are not null? I don't see how this is complicated...

Comment: I don't want to manually type +- 40 fields. What if more fields are added or the names are changed?

Comment: why would you do that? any way you'll be losing information. Anyway, how to do this depends on your requirements, it shouldn't depend on our opinion.

Comment: If a class has 40+ fields it's already messed up. Sure, you can do it with reflection but that will be way slower.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would go for a constructor, for example:

```
public MergedSatellite(final Satellite one, final Satellite other) {
    setOffName((one.getOffName() == null) ? other.getOffName() : one.getOffName());
    // And so on for all fields
}
```

EDIT: Note that this will prime `one` over `other` when the field exists on both instances. You might want to consider more logic on the merging process.

Comment: how would you handle the fields where both have a value?

Comment: @Stultuske I think the constructor I posted already answers your question. `other` wins over `one`, although you can put more logic to handle that kind of situation.

Comment: ok thx, so in your opinion +-40 lines of that code is the way to go? Sorry I'm not that experienced in Java and would like to learn from the pro's:-)

Comment: It highly depends on the situation. If you're expecting the class to change soon/often, then maybe reflection is the way to go (I'm not a big fan of reflection but sometimes there's no other option). If not, 40+- lines should be OK (although like I said, if a class has 40+- fields, [it is screaming for refactoring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/God_object))

Comment: Thx for the god object link! Learned a lot today.

Comment: @m0skit0 indeed, other wins over one? ehm. no, it doesn't, actually. it's the other way around. my point is: you are creating an instance with information that doesn't belong to it, but to another/other instances, and just assuming it'll be correct.

Comment: @Stultuske Yes, right, the other way around. As I said, the code is self-explanatory for that. OP didn't clarify how to merge two objects, and definitely doesn't matter because it's not what is being asked here. As I already said: you can add your own logic for the merging of fields that exist on both instances `one` and `other`. I've updated my answer to make that clear.

Answer (score 3):

Well, using reflection it would be something like this:

```
public static Satellite merge(Satellite s1, Satellite s2) throws Exception {

    Satellite merged = new Satellite();

    for (Field field : Satellite.class.getDeclaredFields()) {
        field.set(merged, field.get(s1) != null? field.get(s1) : field.get(s2));
    }

    return merged;
}
```

But I think this is absolutelly a bad (dangerous and slow) approach. Actually, I would go for `m0skit0` solution, but first please break down your class. You shouldn't have a class with ~40 fields...

Comment: What is so dangerous about that? Maybe since they are Pojo one should use `BeanIntrospector` and invoke setter methods on `merged`.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe [BeanUtils.copyProperties(...)](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/BeanUtils.html#copyProperties-java.lang.Object-java.lang.Object-) from [spring-beans](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-beans) is worth taking a look at.

Answer (score 0):

Really depends on the problem you are trying to solve. What are the constraints and conditions for merging ?

One solution might be to Wrap both classes in class C and use ternary operator for each get method, the code might at least be readable and not verbose.
return isNotBlank(a.getName())?a.getName():b.getName();

There are other options like using java reflection which is generally not recommended.

Answer (score 0):

Using [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson):

```
Satellite resultSatellite = new Satellite();
ObjectReader objectReader = objectMapper.readerForUpdating(resultSatellite);
// inversed order, because in the question, satelliteA's values have to win
objectReader.readValue(objectMapper.<JsonNode>valueToTree(satelliteB));
objectReader.readValue(objectMapper.<JsonNode>valueToTree(satelliteA));
// resultSatellite contains the merged result
```

Important notes:

1. make sure that you use `@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)` on your POJOs or configure this at the `objectMapper` level. This is required in order to avoid overwriting non-null values with nulls
2. make sure to use `@JsonMerge` on the fields containing nested POJOs for [deep merging](https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/misc/jackson/json-merge-annotation.html)